# Copy Constructor does not satisfy `required` property

Tags: c#, c#-11.0

I have a class with a `required` property.  I have created a copy constructor that initializes that property to the same thing that the source instance of that class has.  Why does the compiler give me the error:

CS9035: Required member 'PropertyName' must be set in the object initializer or attribute constructor.

```
public class Class1
{
  public required string Name {get; set;}

  public Class1(){}

  public Class1(Class1 src)
  {
    Name = src.Name;
  }
}

public class OtherClass
{
  public void func()
  {
    // This works fine
    var data = new Class1
    {
      Name = "test"
    };

    // This gives compiler error
    var data1 = new Class1(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) (emphasis added):

> The `required` modifier indicates that the field or property it's applied to must be initialized *by an object initializer*.

The statement `var data1 = new Class1(data);` does not initialize the `Name` property using an object initializer, so you get a compiler error.

You can tell the compiler that your copy constructor initializes all `required` members by adding the `[SetsRequiredMembers]` attribute (available in the `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` namespace):

```
[SetsRequiredMembers]
public Class1(Class1 src)
{
    Name = src.Name;
}
```

No more compiler error!

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I had seen some examples in it where constructors were used interchangeably with object initializers, hence the confusion.